# Transforming an Image to move diagnally

Tags: java, graphics

```
public void draw(Graphics g, Graphics g2d, double theta, int NEWY){

        g.setColor(Color.orange);


        int drawLocationX = character.x;
        int drawLocationY = character.y-47;


        double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians (theta);
        double locationX = this.getWidth()/2;
        double locationY = this.getHeight()/2;
        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);


        g2d.drawImage(op.filter(image, null), drawLocationX, NEWY, null);
}

        public int getHeightWorld(int x){
        //meant to find height of land at specified location
        int highest = 0;
        int checked = 0;

        for(int c = panel.HEIGHT-1; c >= 0; c--){

            if(this.inColRange(x)&& this.inRowRange(c))
            if(LandList[c][x] == 2){
                highest = c;
                checked++;
            }

        }

        return (1000 - highest);
    }


    public double getAngleWorldT1(){
        //meant to find angle tank needs to be rotated at
        int g = this.getHeightWorld(tank1.getNEWX());
        int h = this.getHeightWorld((tank1.getWidth()+ tank1.getNEWX()));
        double trythis = this.NewEquation();
        int newg = tank1.getWidth()+ tank1.getNEWX();
        int newh = tank2.getWidth()+ tank2.getNEWX();
        double newery =  (trythis*newg);
        double newery2 =  (trythis*tank1.getNEWX());
        double newval = newery - newery2;

         double u = 5;
         double width = tank1.getWidth();
         if(Math.abs(h-g) > tank1.getWidth()){

              u = width/(g-h);

         }
         else{
         u = (g-h)/width;

         }

        double p =  57.6846779*Math.asin(Math.toRadians(u));

        return p;
    }
public double NewEquation(){
        int dividethis = 0;
        int subtractthis = 0;
        int numnegative = 0;
        for(int what = 0; what < tank1.getWidth(); what++){

            if(Math.abs(this.getHeightWorld(what)-this.getHeightWorld(what-1)) < 2){
            dividethis += this.getHeightWorld(what);
                if(this.getHeightWorld(what)-this.getHeightWorld(what-1) < 0){
                numnegative++;
            }
            }
            else{
                subtractthis++;
            }
        }
        dividethis = dividethis/(tank1.getWidth()-subtractthis);
        if((numnegative - tank1.getWidth()) > tank1.getWidth()/2){
            dividethis = dividethis*-1;
        }
        return dividethis;

    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        //MOVE TO DIFF METHOD
        int newy = this.getHeightWorld(tank1.getNEWX()) - tank1.getHeight();
        int newy2 = this.getHeightWorld(tank2.getNEWX()) - tank2.getHeight();
        if( LandList[newy][tank1.getNEWX()] == 2){
            while (LandList[newy][tank1.getNEWX()] == 2){
            newy--;
//          System.out.println("FIRST HERE");
//          System.out.println(newy);
            }
//          System.out.println("FIRST");
        }
        if( LandList[newy+1][tank1.getNEWX()] != 2){
            while (LandList[newy+1][tank1.getNEWX()] != 2){
            newy++;
//          System.out.println("SECOND HERE");
            }
//          System.out.println("SECOND");
        }

//System.out.println("YESSSSS" +Math.toDegrees(this.getAngleWorldT1()) );
        tank1.draw(g, g, Math.toDegrees(this.getAngleWorldT1()), newy - tank1.getHeight()-50);
        tank2.draw(g, g, Math.toDegrees(this.getAngleWorldT2()), newy2 - tank2.getHeight());


        //      System.out.println("2");
        for(int x = 0; x < platforms.size(); x++){
            platforms.get(x).draw(g);
        }

    }

}
```

(Sorry for the messy code.)

These are two classes I am using to design a tank shooter game. In this portion, I am attempting to make the image rotate according to the land it is over(to appear traveling uphill or downhill) and I don't want any piece inside of the land. "LandList" is a 2D array that has a value of 2 if there is land and 1 if there is no land. Two issues is A) rotating at incorrect heights and not rotating at all points
B)Image cuts off at a certain height

Thank you for your help.

BOTH CLASSES IN FULL

```
public class World {

    Land[][] land;
    List<Land> platforms = new ArrayList<Land>();


    private GraphicsPanel panel;
    int[][] LandList = new int[800][1500];
    private int delay = 30;
    private Timer timer;
    private Random r;
    Tank tank1;
    Tank tank2;

    public World(GraphicsPanel marioPanel) {

        panel = marioPanel;
        land = new Land[panel.WIDTH][panel.HEIGHT-500-3];

        setUpWorld();
        setUpTimer();

    }

    private void setUpWorld() {

        for(int r = 0; r < panel.WIDTH; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < panel.HEIGHT; c++){
                LandList[c][r] = 1;
            }
        }
        //tank not displaying
        //a lot of stuff copied over
        tank1 = new Tank(25,442,100,60,1);
        tank2 = new Tank(700,442,100,60,2);
        r = new Random();

        int w = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < panel.WIDTH; x+=5){
            if(x > 0 && x < panel.WIDTH/6 +1){

                //for(int y = (int) (500+(-(100*Math.random())*((x%2)+1))); y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                for(int y = 500; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                    Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
                    platforms.add(creating);
                    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
                            if(inRowRange(x+r) && inColRange(y+c))
                                LandList[y+r][x+c] = 2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if(x > panel.WIDTH/6 && x < 2*panel.WIDTH/6 +1){

                //for(int y = (int) (500+(-(100*Math.random())*((x%2)+1))); y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                for(int y = 500+ 4*w; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                    Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
                    platforms.add(creating);
                    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
                            if(inRowRange(y+r) && inColRange(x+c))
                                LandList[y+r][x+c] = 2;
                        }
                    }

                }
                w--;
            }
            if(x > 2*panel.WIDTH/6 && x < 3*panel.WIDTH/6 +1){

                //for(int y = (int) (500+(-(100*Math.random())*((x%2)+1))); y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                for(int y = 500+ 4*w; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                    Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
                    platforms.add(creating);
                    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
                            if(inRowRange(y+r) && inColRange(x+c))
                                LandList[y+r][x+c] = 2;
                        }
                    }

                }
                w++;
            }
            if(x > 3*panel.WIDTH/6 && x < 4*panel.WIDTH/6 +1){

                //for(int y = (int) (500+(-(100*Math.random())*((x%2)+1))); y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                for(int y = 500+ 4*n; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                    Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
                    platforms.add(creating);
                    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
                            if(inRowRange(y+r) && inColRange(x+c))
                                LandList[y+r][x+c] = 2;
                        }
                    }

                }
                n--;
            }
            if(x > 4*panel.WIDTH/6 && x < 5*panel.WIDTH/6 +1){

                //for(int y = (int) (500+(-(100*Math.random())*((x%2)+1))); y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                for(int y = 500+ 4*n; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                    Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
                    platforms.add(creating);
                    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
                            if(inRowRange(y+r) && inColRange(x+c))
                                LandList[y+r][x+c] = 2;

                        }
                    }

                }
                n++;
            }
            if(x > 5*panel.WIDTH/6){

                //for(int y = (int) (500+(-(100*Math.random())*((x%2)+1))); y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                for(int y = 500; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
                    Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
                    platforms.add(creating);
                    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
                        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
                            if(inRowRange(y+r) && inColRange(x+c))
                            LandList[y+r][x+c] = 2;
                        //  System.out.println(LandList[x+r][y+c]);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            //              else{
            //                  for(int y = 500; y < panel.HEIGHT; y+=5){
            //                      Land creating = new Land(x, y, 5, 5);
            //                      platforms.add(creating);
            //                  }
            //              
            //              }
        }
        for(int r = 0; r < panel.WIDTH; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < panel.HEIGHT; c++){
                //System.out.println(LandList[r][c]);
            }
        }
        for(int checked = 0; checked < panel.WIDTH; checked++){
            System.out.println(this.getHeightWorld(checked));
        }
//      System.out.println(LandList);
    }



    private boolean inColRange(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i>=0 && i<LandList[0].length;
    }

    private boolean inRowRange(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i>=0 && i<LandList.length;
    }

    private void setUpTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // what should happen each time the timer goes off?

                panel.repaint();
                moveStuff();
                checkHitBoxes();
                //System.out.println(mario.getY());

            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }



    protected void checkHitBoxes() {

    }


    protected void moveStuff() {
        tank1.move();
        panel.repaint();

    }

    public int getHeightWorld(int x){
        //meant to find height of land at specified location
        int highest = 0;
        int checked = 0;

        for(int c = panel.HEIGHT-1; c >= 0; c--){

            if(this.inColRange(x)&& this.inRowRange(c))
            if(LandList[c][x] == 2){
                highest = c;
                checked++;
            }

        }

        return (1000 - highest);
    }


    public double getAngleWorldT1(){
        //meant to find angle tank needs to be rotated at
        int g = this.getHeightWorld(tank1.getNEWX());
        int h = this.getHeightWorld((tank1.getWidth()+ tank1.getNEWX()));
        double trythis = this.NewEquation();
        int newg = tank1.getWidth()+ tank1.getNEWX();
        int newh = tank2.getWidth()+ tank2.getNEWX();
        double newery =  (trythis*newg);
        double newery2 =  (trythis*tank1.getNEWX());
        double newval = newery - newery2;

         double u = 5;
         double width = tank1.getWidth();
         if(Math.abs(h-g) > tank1.getWidth()){

              u = width/(g-h);

         }
         else{
         u = (g-h)/width;

         }

        double p =  57.6846779*Math.asin(Math.toRadians(u));

        return p;
    }
    public double getAngleWorldT2(){
        int a = this.getHeightWorld(tank2.getNEWX());
        int s = this.getHeightWorld((tank2.getWidth() + tank2.getNEWX() + 100) );
//       a = 100;
//       s = 700;
        int o = (a-s)/tank2.getWidth();
        //System.out.println(o);
        double p =  -57.6846779*(Math.asin(Math.toRadians(o)));
        //System.out.println(p);
        return p;


    }

    public double NewEquation(){
        int dividethis = 0;
        int subtractthis = 0;
        int numnegative = 0;
        for(int what = 0; what < tank1.getWidth(); what++){

            if(Math.abs(this.getHeightWorld(what)-this.getHeightWorld(what-1)) < 2){
            dividethis += this.getHeightWorld(what);
                if(this.getHeightWorld(what)-this.getHeightWorld(what-1) < 0){
                numnegative++;
            }
            }
            else{
                subtractthis++;
            }
        }
        dividethis = dividethis/(tank1.getWidth()-subtractthis);
        if((numnegative - tank1.getWidth()) > tank1.getWidth()/2){
            dividethis = dividethis*-1;
        }
        return dividethis;

    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        //MOVE TO DIFF METHOD
        int newy = this.getHeightWorld(tank1.getNEWX()) - tank1.getHeight();
        int newy2 = this.getHeightWorld(tank2.getNEWX()) - tank2.getHeight();
        if( LandList[newy][tank1.getNEWX()] == 2){
            while (LandList[newy][tank1.getNEWX()] == 2){
            newy--;
//          System.out.println("FIRST HERE");
//          System.out.println(newy);
            }
//          System.out.println("FIRST");
        }
        if( LandList[newy+1][tank1.getNEWX()] != 2){
            while (LandList[newy+1][tank1.getNEWX()] != 2){
            newy++;
//          System.out.println("SECOND HERE");
            }
//          System.out.println("SECOND");
        }

//System.out.println("YESSSSS" +Math.toDegrees(this.getAngleWorldT1()) );
        tank1.draw(g, g, Math.toDegrees(this.getAngleWorldT1()), newy - tank1.getHeight()-50);
        tank2.draw(g, g, Math.toDegrees(this.getAngleWorldT2()), newy2 - tank2.getHeight());


        //      System.out.println("2");
        for(int x = 0; x < platforms.size(); x++){
            platforms.get(x).draw(g);
        }

    }

}

public class Tank extends Moveable{


    private boolean moveRight,moveLeft;
    private String direction = "NONE";
    private int dx =5;

    //graphics
    BufferedImage image = null;
    private URL file;
    private Rectangle character;
    private Rectangle hitBox;
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
     private int NEWX;

    public Tank(int x, int y, int w, int h, int color){


        character = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);

        this.create(null,x,y,w,h);
        NEWX = character.x;
        BufferedImage img =null;
        if(color == 1){
//          file= getClass().getResource("pictures\\green_tank1"); 
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("green_tank1.png"));
                image = img;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
//          file = getClass().getResource("pictures\\blue_tank1");
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("blue_tank1.png"));
                image = img;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g, Graphics g2d, double theta, int NEWY){

        g.setColor(Color.orange);


        int drawLocationX = character.x;
        int drawLocationY = character.y-47;


        double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians (theta);
        double locationX = this.getWidth()/2;
        double locationY = this.getHeight()/2;
        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);


        g2d.drawImage(op.filter(image, null), drawLocationX, NEWY, null);
        //System.out.println("This is new X " + NEWX);
//      label.setVisible(true);
//      label.isOpaque();
//      label.setBounds(character.x, character.y, character.width, character.height);
//      label.repaint();
        //g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
//      int centerx = character.x + character.width/2;
//      int centery = character.y + character.height/2;
//  
//      int point1 = (int) (centerx + (character.width/2)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)) - (character.height/2)* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
//      int point2 = (int) (centery + (character.height/2)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta))+(character.width/2)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
//      int point3 =(int) (centerx - (character.width/2)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)) + (character.height/2)* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
//      int point4 = (int) (centery - (character.height/2)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta))-(character.width/2)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)));
//      //System.out.println(theta);
//      g.drawImage(image, point1,point2,point3,point4, null);
////        System.out.println("3");



        // Rotation information



//      AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians (theta), character.x, character.y);
//      AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
//  
//      // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations
//      g.drawImage(op.filter((BufferedImage) image, null), character.x, character.y, null);





//      System.out.println(this.getX());
//      System.out.println(this.getY());
//      System.out.println(this.getWidth());
//      System.out.println(this.getHeight());
//      g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
//      this.setBounds(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
//      
    }



    public Rectangle getRect(){
        return this.character;
    }
    public void move(){

        if(moveLeft == true){

            character.setBounds(character.x -2, character.y, character.width, character.height);
            character.x = character.x -2;
            NEWX += -2;
        }
        if(moveRight == true){
            character.setBounds(character.x +2, character.y, character.width, character.height);
            character.x = character.x +2;
            NEWX += 2;
        }

    }
    public void setDirection(String s){
        this.direction =  s;
        String x = s.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1);

        if(x.equals("L")){
            //System.out.println(x);
            moveLeft = true;

            moveRight = false;


        }
        if(x.equals("R")){
            moveRight = true;

            moveLeft = false;
//          System.out.println("im here");

        }
        else if(x.equals("N")){
            moveRight = false;
            moveLeft =false;
//          System.out.println("I Got Here #2");
        }
    }

    public String getDirection(){
        return this.direction;
    }

    public int getNEWX(){
        return this.NEWX;
    }


}
```

Comment: i did not include the entire class, just methods involved

Comment: " The first draw method is in my "Tank" class while the rest are in my "World" class

Comment: The tank class controls things universal to all tanks while world contains most of the actual game mechanics